# Adding paginating to my class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, will-paginate

I have a class, I'd like to call it a model but it's a class which read from a rest api.

In it I call the following method like so `MyClass.get_profiles` which returns an array of objects which from the view works just like it came from active record.

```
def self.get_profiles()
    resulthash = get_server_response "/management/admin/profiles", :query => {:playerType=>:all}

    a = Array.new

    resulthash["users"].each do |u|
        a.push(OpenStruct.new(u))
    end

    a
end
```

What I am on doing is adding `limit` and `skip` in the parameters for the api which uses mongodb in the background (i can only access it via rest)

How can I then from my controller and view have paginating ability?

I would like to use will_paginate, or is there a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

will_paginate adds two extra attributes to the collection for generating the links, 'total_pages' and 'current_page'.

If you add these two attributes to your returning array, will_paginate's helper could work.